# how to create a multi select box with out selected options codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-form-helper

hi i am using `codeigniter` , i want to add a `multi select box` to my page ,

i saw the codeigniter user guide example , but what it is doing is set the values in multi select .

like this

```
$options = array(
                  'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
                  'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
                  'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
                  'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
                );

$shirts_on_sale = array('small', 'large');

echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, $shirts_on_sale);
```

in this multi select box created like this

```
<select name="shirts" multiple="multiple">
<option value="small" selected="selected">Small Shirt</option>
<option value="med">Medium Shirt</option>
<option value="large" selected="selected">Large Shirt</option>
<option value="xlarge">Extra Large Shirt</option>
</select>
```

it have to give the options to be selected in  `$shirts_on_sale` array , but in my case i want to create a multi select but `dont want selected options`  i tried to pass an empty array . but it is not working

like this

```
$array = array();
echo form_dropdown('shirts', $substore_details, $array);
```

how to create a multi select with no selected items . please help..............

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the form_multiselect() helper.

```
$options = array(
                  'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
                  'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
                  'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
                  'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
                );

echo form_multiselect('shirts', $options);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to my mind is using an array with more than one empty element:

```
$options = array(
                  'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
                  'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
                  'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
                  'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
                );

$array = array('','');
echo form_dropdown('shirts',$options, $array);
```

This code works, though not the most elegant out there.

## **UPDATE:**

This is even better, didn't remember it at first!

```
echo form_multiselect('shirts',$options,'','');
```

Output:

```
<select name="shirts" multiple="multiple">
<option value="small">Small Shirt</option>
<option value="med">Medium Shirt</option>
<option value="large">Large Shirt</option>
<option value="xlarge">Extra Large Shirt</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya Please see my update answer for an even better method

Answer (score 1):

i tried every solution but no one works with me 
i tried ( form_dropdown from from helper) 
i also tried ordinary way with multiple= "multiple"

is it common problem with codeigniter ??

**Update**
the error was that anyone forget to name in html attribute as array cars[]

```
<select **name="cars[]"** multiple="multiple">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

this works fine always .

Answer (score 0):

Old version of codeigniter doesn't have `form_multiselect()`.
Next code should work

```
$array = array();
echo form_dropdown('shirts', $substore_details, $array, 'multiple');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$options = array(
  'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
  'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
  'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
  'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
);    
echo form_dropdown('shirts[]',$options);
```

Comment: Can you explain that code a bit? What did you change and why? Additionally, this question is more then seven years old and already holds some answers, so you should explain what makes yours different

Answer (score 0):

We have a one array and we want to show selected values of this array in multi selector

```
$show_selected = array("USA", "Poland", "Japan");
```

For this I have used in_array to show selected values in selector

```
<select class="form-control js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your country</option>
  <option <?php if(in_array(1,$show_selected)) echo "selected";?>  value="1">USA</option>
  <option <?php if(in_array(2,$show_selected)) echo "selected";?> value="2">Germany</option>
  <option <?php if(in_array(3,$show_selected)) echo "selected";?> value="3">France</option>
  <option <?php if(in_array(4,$show_selected)) echo "selected";?>  value="4">Poland</option>
  <option <?php if(in_array(5,$show_selected)) echo "selected";?> value="5">Japan</option>
</select>
<button class="btn-save btn btn-primary btn-sm">Save</button>
```